# TableView in UIView em Swift 2.0

Tags: swift, uitableview, uitableviewcell

Estou a tentar criar uma tabela dentro de uma view. Para que quando o utilizador se encontrar na view1 e carregar num botão abra uma view2 mais pequena dentro da view1 e escolha um dos dados da tabela e ao carregar transporta os dados selecionados para a view1.

Comecei por fazer isto na view1:

```
    carViewSelect.frame = CGRectMake(10, 70, 355, 580)
    carViewSelect.layer.borderColor  = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
    carViewSelect.layer.borderWidth = borderSizeView
    carViewSelect.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    carViewSelect.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.9)
    view.addSubview(carViewSelect)
    
    
    listCars.frame = CGRectMake(10, 35, 340, 490)
    listCars.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
    listCars.numberOfRowsInSection(5)
    var indexPath = NSIndexPath()
    let cell : UITableViewCell = listCars.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier)! as UITableViewCell
    cell.textLabel!.text = "hello WOrld"
    cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    listCars.indexPathForCell(cell)
    listCars.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
    carViewSelect.addSubview(listCars)
```

No entanto o resultado que obtive foi uma tabela vazia, como mostra a imagem:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A ideia seria colocar uma imagem no inicio da cell, depois uma label e depois outra imagem.
Os dados para preencherem a tabela vêem num NSMutableArray

Comment: Já definiu no viewDidLoad o delegate e o datasource?

Comment: Já avencei um pouco e no controlView instanciei a tabela da seguinte forma 'let ab : TableView = TableView(frame: CGRectMake(10, 35, 340, 490))
        carViewSelect.addSubview(ab)
        ab.addActionBar(self)' . e desta forma já consegui adicionar os resultados pretendidos na tabela, o entanto o método didSelectRowAtIndexPath não está a ser chamado quando carrego numa "Cell"

Comment: Coloca o código dessa parte pra ter uma idéia do que está acontecendo...

Comment: @JadsonMedeiros, já consegui obter o resultado que queria, só tenho um problema quando entro na view2 em 1º lugar vou carregar a tabela com os dados, e quando saiu gostaria de limpar a tabela. Pois se voltar a chamar a view2 ela vai carregar a tabela de novo e vai duplicar os resultados na tabela. Tem como esvaziar a tabela quando saiu da view? Obrigado

Comment: Vc está usando banco de dados? caso sim ou não, o procedimento é o mesmo... vc pode fazer o seguinte, já que vc supostamente usa um array com strings pra popular a view2, vc pode no comando que faz vc voltar pra view1, apagar todos os dados do array que populam a view2. Quando vc estiver na view1 e clicar para mostrar a view2, a view1 preenche o array com os dados necessários para view2 e não duplicados e manda pra view2 mostrar normalmente.

Comment: Estou a usar banco de dados sim, por isso sempre que chamo a view2 vou buscar os dados á bd. E como faço para apagar todos os dados do array é que já o fiz de algumas maneiras e não tive sucesso

Comment: SeuArray.removeAll() para apagar o array, porem vc tem que fazer o procedimento:quando for da view1 para a view2, primeiramente apagar todos os dados do banco e depois inserir os dados novos, assim sempre o banco estará atualizado e sem dados repetidos.